# Case statement with max and null value

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper

I have a table:

[image]

I need to select the tow `c_id` where

- date values is null and
- max date from date column.

There can be more than 2 date values in the `DATE` column.

Output will be select the `c_id` **3** & **4**.

How  can I write this in a single case statement?

Comment: can you show what you have already tried and the point at which you are either getting an error or having trouble understanding how the code works? At least some pseudocode

Comment: Punctuation exists for a reason; I suggest you use it. I tried to fix formatting; hopefully, it is somewhat better now. Though, what did you mean by saying "tow c_id"? What is "tow"? Two? Row? Something different?

Comment: I don't see how [PL/SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/overview.html) or [PL/SQL Developer](https://www.allroundautomations.com/products/pl-sql-developer/) are related to the question, which seems to be about SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Analytics might help; order values by the `DATE` column descending, with additional `NULLS FIRST` clause. For example:

```
SQL> with test (a_id, c_id, c_date) as
  2    (select 1, 2, date '2017-05-20' from dual union all
  3     select 1, 3, date '2017-07-17' from dual union all
  4     select 1, 4, null              from dual
  5    )
  6  select a_id, c_id, c_date
  7  from (select a_id, c_id, c_date,
  8          row_number () over (partition by a_id
  9                              order by c_date desc nulls first) rn
 10        from test
 11       )
 12  where rn <= 2;

      A_ID       C_ID C_DATE
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          4
         1          3 2017-07-17

SQL>
```